# iOS Share text and/or image using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share an image and text using UIActivityViewController. It works but I would like to set it up so that it shares the image and optionally shares some text. If I only share the image I get a longer list of apps to choose from. If I include the text as well, fewer apps are available. Ex: Instagram is available when sharing an image, but it is not available when I share an image and text. Is there a way to specify the text as optional so that apps that support only image sharing also show up?

Here's is the code that I have so far

```
NSMutableArray * activityItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[self.message]];

if(self.image){
    [activityItems addObject:self.image];
}

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self.viewController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```